# Is it possible to cache the same WMS service based on a vendor parameter?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, cache

I'm exploring optimization techniques for caching data coming back from a Digital Globe service. We have two unique identifiers we use for their WMS GetMap service that will give us low or hi-res raster images. I'd like to cache both, but the only different between the two is simply a vendor parameter called 'connectid'.

In the end, we'll cache at least one of them, but we'll need to make a choice of which one if it's not possible to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been a few days. I've since given up on GeoWebCache and flopped over to [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/). It's MUCH more customizable. It's yaml configuration is open enough to allow me to specify the vendor keys in its own config, along with as many different providers/layers/caching routines I need.

I highly recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Parameter Filter to pass through an arbitrary request parameters while controlling the set of allowed values.

For instance, to allow the `resolution` parameter to take the values `high` or `low`, and to force it to `low` when it's not specified, you would use a filter like this:

```
<stringParameterFilter>
  <key>resolution</key>
  <defaultValue>low</defaultValue>
  <values>
    <string>high</string>
    <string>low</string>
  </values>
</stringParameterFilter>
```

There's a chapter on parameters in the [GWC manual](http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/configuration/layers/parameterfilters.html)